# Loading an individual file on any directory request (Apache)

Tags: apache

I wish to load a particular .html file on request of *any* directory w/ Apache.

For example if I were to request somewebsite.com/thisDirectory from my web browser index.html would load, however if I were to request somewebsite.com/anotherDirectory the same index.html would also render.

Answer (score 0):

You could use URL rewriting:

```
RewriteEngin On
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.html [L]
```